# os-svc-daemon is not adding a new service to upstart

Tags: openstack, upstart, python-daemon, os-svc-daemon

I have created a new service named some-service. The shell script is present in /etc/init.d/some-service I have the same shell script file in /usr/local/bin/some-service which is a copy of some-service.

i ran the below command to create a daemon service:

```
os-svc-daemon -i $INSTALLDIR -d some-service some-service root some-service
```

This created a /etc/init/some-service.conf

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]


env OS_SVC_ENABLE_CONTROL=1
export OS_SVC_ENABLE_CONTROL

pre-start script
  mkdir -p /var/run/some-service
  chown -R root:root /var/run/some-service
end script

respawn
# the default post-start of 1 second sleep delays respawning enough to
# not hit the default of 10 times in 5 seconds. Make it 2 times in 5s.
respawn limit 2 5

exec start-stop-daemon --start -c root --exec **INSTALLDIR**/bin/some-service --

post-start exec sleep 1
```

to reload the changes ran the below command

```
initctl reload-configuration
```

in tried to start the service but it never runs.

```
initctl start some-service
```

What am i doing wrong here? Also is it safe to use shell script to start it and not a python bin file?

Answer (score 0):

Use os-svc-enable servicename and try start servicename

Comment: Can you be specific ?  i tried "os-svc-enable -n service-name" and then "os-svc-restart -n service-name". Still on killing the service, it does not start up